# Why is Eclipse Maven Archetype plugin not showing my locally installed Maven archetype?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I installed the Maven archetype [java8-junit5-archetype](https://github.com/thiagoprocaci/java8-junit5-archetype) locally, but when I try to create a new Maven project in Eclipse, the Maven Archetype plugin doesn't list it.

I manually added the entry to the local catalog file `~/.m2/archetype-catalog.xml` as such:

```
<archetype>
      <groupId>com.tbp</groupId>
      <artifactId>java8-junit5-archetype</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <repository></repository>
</archetype>
```

But In Eclipse, I don't see `java8-junit5-archetype` listed.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Root Cause**
It turns out the reason why the [java8-junit5-archetype](https://github.com/thiagoprocaci/java8-junit5-archetype) wasn't listed, is because its version is `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. That makes it a `snapshot archetype`.

**Solution**
Check the `Include snapshot archetypes` checkbox. Now the archetype is listed.
[image]